# Downgrading NodeJs to below version using `n` package Not Working?

Tags: node.js, bitnami

I have a virtual machine running `Bitnami` and my current `Nodejs` version is `v9.8.0` but i wanted to change my version to `8.11.1` and to do that i used `n` npm package but still the version of NodeJs is same.

I used below commands

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n 8.11.1
```

Can anyone please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Bitnami Engineer here.

Bitnami Stacks are completely self-contained and run independently of the rest of the software or libraries installed on your system. This means that you don't have to worry about installing any other software on your system to make the new application work. They also won't interfere with any software already installed on your system, so everything you're already running will continue to work normally.

In this case, the PATH environment variable is configured to use the Bitnami binaries before the system's ones

```
PATH=/opt/bitnami/redis/bin:/opt/bitnami/python/bin:/opt/bitnami/nodejs/bin:/opt/bitnami/git/bin:/opt/bitnami/apache2/bin:/opt/bitnami/common/bin:/opt/bitnami/redis/bin:/opt/bitnami/python/bin:/opt/bitnami/nodejs/bin:/opt/bitnami/git/bin:/opt/bitnami/apache2/bin:/opt/bitnami/common/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

In case you try to find all the node binaries in the system

```
bitnami@bitnami-nodejs-dm-1072:~$ which -a node
/opt/bitnami/nodejs/bin/node
/opt/bitnami/nodejs/bin/node
/usr/local/bin/node
```

The first 2 "node" is the Bitnami's ones, the 3rd one is the system's one. If you use it, you will have the new Node.js version that you installed

```
bitnami@bitnami-nodejs-dm-1072:~$ /usr/local/bin/node --version
v8.11.1
```

Comment: Actually, i am using package 0x and the command from which I run my server is `0x app.js` now how can i make this package run my app.js using system NodeJs version which is 8.11.1

Comment: You can specify the node binary you want to use `0x -- /usr/local/bin/node app.js` https://www.npmjs.com/package/0x